# onTouchListener with a new dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I have an app that inside onItemLongClick opens a dialog. I want the user to have a better experience so I want the possibility to choose and item in the dialog without having to raise his finger but I can't understand how to make a onTouch listener that will get the MOVE MotionEvent. can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks,
Benny.

Answer (score 0):

Any onTouchListener will get move events, unless the moves are stolen from it.  Given you're in an onItemLongClick, are you part of a ListView?  If so, you'll get ACTION_CANCEL whenever the listview decides to take the touch events away from its children to scroll with, and you won't receive further moves (or even an up).

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any way I can change this? make the dialog to get the events? in which cases the action is stolen?